# Hide desktop.ini and Thumbs.db files

Tags: windows, files, file-format, filemanager, hidden-files

I have Ubuntu and Windows 7 on my computer. Now I have a problem, I want to hide the *desktop.ini* and *Thumbs.db* files Windows automaticly creates.

I can't rename all files to *.desktop.ini* and *.Thumbs.db*. If I do this, Windows creates new *desktop.ini* and *Thumbs.db* files.

Adding those files in the ".hidden" file in the home directory don't help me either.

How can I hide *desktop.ini* and *Thumbs.db* in directories when I use Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use .hidden on all the folders that contain the files you want to hide.

Lets say you have 3 folders with photos

folder1
folder2
folder2

You have to create a .hidden file for folder1, folder2 and folder3. Not just 1 file in your ~/user.

Comment: Oh, it's bad. i think, that i can only add .hidden file in home foldier

Comment: See [#18451](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18451/how-to-hide-in-thunar-and-nautilus-a-directory-without-putting-a-dot-in-its-nam) for automating the task.